# Trying to open .txt files in batch and have it go back to a menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
:1
title Opening...                         Twitch Mod Helper v1.0
C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\ModHelper\Files\currnet.txt
GOTO main
```

When I do this it doesn't open the .txt and goes to the GOTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simple call a `.txt` file. You need to either open it in notepad or type it:

#### Open in Notepad:

```
:1
title Opening...                         Twitch Mod Helper v1.0
start notepad.exe C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\ModHelper\Files\currnet.txt
GOTO main
```

#### Open in Notepad and Wait:

```
:1
title Opening...                         Twitch Mod Helper v1.0
notepad.exe C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\ModHelper\Files\currnet.txt
GOTO main
```

#### Type in CMD:

```
:1
title Opening...                         Twitch Mod Helper v1.0
type C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\ModHelper\Files\currnet.txt
Echo.
GOTO main
```

#### Type in CMD and Wait

```
:1
title Opening...                         Twitch Mod Helper v1.0
type C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\ModHelper\Files\currnet.txt
Echo.
pause
GOTO main
```